# How to represent the variable by combine static & varying parts

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my question:
For example, I have four lists here:

```
 list_a = [1,2,3]
 list_b = [4,5,6]
 list_c = [7,8,9]
 list_d = [7,10,12]
```

I want to call these lists using loop.
Define:

```
 var = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

If it's in string format, I can use `'list_%s' %(var[i])` to get 'list_a','list_b','list_c','list_d'.

My target:

```
for i in range(0,len(var),1):
    -----set list_var = list_var[i]--I don't know how to achieve it in code--------
    print list_var
```

Comment: This is very hard to understand. What does the last line mean?

Comment: Why dont you use a dictionary of lists? `{ "a": [1,2,3], "b": ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eval` function in python

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = [4,5,6]
list_c = [7,8,9]
list_d = [7,10,12]

letter = "a"

list = eval('list_%s' % (letter))
```

This question is meant to directly answer your question. Although this is how you'd dynamically generate a variable name and get its value, it is not a good practice and there are better ways to reorganise your code and make it better. (Dictionaries for example)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll accept your answer after 8 min.